# What is the cheapest way of getting to Abbotsford Airport from Vancouver?

Tags: public-transport, airport-transfer, vancouver

[Swoop](https://flyswoop.com/) recently launched cheap flights from Abbotsford Airport to other Canadian cities. However I'm having difficulties figuring out a cheap way of getting there from Vancouver - it seems that there aren't any direct connections and the [only shuttle bus](http://www.valleyairporter.ca/) costs $50 just to get to Surrey.

Are there any other options I'm missing? Or perhaps a car rental is the cheapest option?

Comment: Did you find the [ground transportation page on the Abbotsford Airport website?](https://www.abbotsfordairport.ca/Travellers/ground_transportation.htm)  It certainly seems to imply that the only transit options that go directly to the airport are a shuttle service (which you found) and taxis.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert yes I did but airport websites are often out of date or incomplete

Comment: Note too that if flying to the Toronto area, Swoop will serve John C. Munro Airport in Hamilton, so you'll have a transportation issue at that end as well.  (On the other hand, if going to Niagara Falls/St. Catharines, Hamilton airport is actually a better choice.)

Comment: @JimMackenzie going to Toronto I'd probably rent a car anyway as public transport sucks there for anything outside of the city center. But I'd rather not pay for a rental car to be parked through the weekend.

Comment: @JonathanReez Public transit is indeed good in the city centre, but beyond, a car is easier.  Mind, the freeways (particularly Highway 401) are some of the most congested in the world.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Changing this answer since Greyhound not longer serves Western Canada.

Luckily ebus has stepped in and runs straight from [Abbotsford Airport to Vancouver](https://www.busbud.com/en/bus-abbotsford-vancouver/r/c28yzz-c2b2nm). (I work for Busbud, the linked ticketing site.)

Comment: [Here's the Abbotsford "airport" bus stop on Street View,](https://www.google.ca/maps/@49.0290642,-122.3783628,3a,75y,172.49h,88.15t/data=!3m6!1e1!3m4!1sZSwda03z2u-58ueH01l6Gw!2e0!7i13312!8i6656?hl=en) which I find quite charming.  Note that the stop about 1 km from the terminal, and the roads between the terminal and the bus stop have no sidewalks for most of the way.